# How to send email directly TO a google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

Say I have 2 google sheets: sheet1 and sheet2. My dream is as follows: 
1. create two email addresses for these sheets, say sheet1@email.com and sheet2@email.com respectively 
2. When I send an email to sheet1@email.com from anywhere, the content of that email is created as a new row in sheet1 
3. Likewise for sheet2@email.com and sheet2

Is this possible?

I tried searching for a solution, but could find only articles about how to send emails FROM sheets, and not TO sheets.

Comment: Use a [time trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to check for new [Gmail messages](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app) and them to your spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks, @Diego . Haven't tried timed triggers, looks like this will satisfy the requirement, in a way.